# Passing pointer from c to asm and add value to sse register

Tags: c, assembly, parameter-passing

I want to pass the pointer to an array between C and ASM code. I've got an array of four double values and i need to pass them to asm, load them to xmm, multiply and return the pointer to four values back to C. I've got an error while loading data to xmm0.

How to pass this pointers to ASM and back to C ?
How to load all four numbers to xmm0 ?

Here is the code:

```
.text

.globl calkasse
.type calkasse, @function

calkasse:   
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp

movq 8(%rbp), %rax
movaps 16(%rax), %xmm0
mulps %xmm0,%xmm0

movq  %rbp,   %rsp
popq   %rbp
ret
```

and C code:

```
double (*calkasse(double (*)[4]))[4];

int main(void) {

double suma=0.0;
double poczatek=1.0;
double koniec=5.0;
double step=0.001;
double i=poczatek;
double array[4];
double (*wynik)[4];

    array[0] = i;
    array[1] = i+step;
    array[2] = i+(2*step);
    array[3] = i+(3*step);
    wynik = calkasse(&array);
    suma+=*wynik[0]+*wynik[1]+*wynik[2]+*wynik[3];
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Probably not like this. On Linux and Windows (64bit), the first few arguments are passed in registers (but different ones, and a different number of them). What platform is this for? Also, they're doubles, but you're using them as floats. Four of them will not fit in an xmm register.

Comment: This is linux ubuntu. So the pointer will be in normal register ? I'll change to floats then.

Comment: The argument will be in `rdi` then.

Comment: ok, but how to pass the adrress back ? should i move it to rax ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, but where will you put the thing it's pointing to? If you use the callee's stack, after that returns, the caller will believe that memory belongs to it (in its Red Zone) and it would be allowed to overwrite it before you get a chance to access the result. It might not do that, so it may appear to work. It would probably be better to give that function a pointer to output to.

Comment: ok so i pass it like that: movq %xmm0, (%rsi) where %rsi is a pointer to result array but i've got only result[0] and result[1], result 3 and 4 are zero. Why ?

Comment: Because `movq` only moves 8 bytes, try `movaps`

Comment: Ok, that is what i needed. Thanks for your help, if you want u can add the answer with all that so i can mark it ;)

Comment: Have you considered using _intrinsics_ instead ? This function is hardly large enough to be worth separating out into assembly, and (if I understand you right in what it's supposed to do) could be done by two `_mm_mul_pd()`. If you were to code it in plain C, how would it look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compile  your project as an assembly file, and THEN make these changes.  If you use inline assembly, what happens is that there is a TON (and i mean a ton from what i've seen in my testing) of changes to the system between your C code and inline assembly.  Basically, it destroys the state of the system as you see it before entering the assembly portion.  Its obvious why this is since your C code is going to have to use a C library to even figure out what the inline assembly means.  Thus, your persistence will be destroyed during this, and values will be pushed and popped.

To not destroy your registers before entering the assembly, you can try to add your assembly in the object file after its created.  You can use GDB to figure out what your code is doing before you start adding to it, and you should be able to manually get the address you're looking for, and then you can just place it in a variable.  I would place it in a variable, because if you insert it into a register, you'd have to trace the assembly after your added code to make sure you placed it in the right register at the correct time.  If you place it a variable, you can use a mov instruction (or leal IIRC) to get the pointer value into the variable, and then in your C code, you can just set this variable to null.  Then, you can write your C code before you actually write the assembly manually (basically the variable is a mock).  Hope this helps, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your compiler behave predictably. A C function can be compiled in many ways. It is also OS and platform dependant. So for instance, allowing function parameter passing via registers / register optimizations / os forbidden registers ... these will change the compilation. Try writing a function with optimizations off, and look assembly output of the compiler. That way you will have a *more* controlled case of compilation which will be consistent at least on one os and platform... Then you can add your inline assembly to that function. Always keep an eye on assembly output... This needs medium reverse engineering.